On hover, display overlay element but it is blinking
I have a canvas and overlay text on top of it. I want to display the text only if mouse is hovering on the canvas.
It is working on simple HTML https://codepen.io/Ariel-Ariel-the-bold/pen/MYgvvxZ


.rootc {
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
}

.div1 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.div1:hover ~ .div2 {
  display: flex;
}

.div2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: yellow;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: none;
}
<div class="rootc">
  <div class="container">
    <canvas class="div1"></canvas>
    <div class="div2">
      <h1>This is a text</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>



but not on vue app https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/blue-surf-h8gm3l
on vue app, it is blinking
how do I achieve this on vue app ?

On vue it looks looks like when you hover on div1 you display div2 which then kind of top over div1 which is not hovered any more and keeps cycling this way.

The CSS in your Vue app sandbox is completely different to the CSS in the working example.

I don't know if this can be a solution for you on Vue but if you add this as well it is solved  .div2:hover {   display: flex; }

.div2 appears on top of the .div1, so mouse is no longer hovering over .div1, so .div2 dissappears, so mouse again hovering over .div1, so .div2 appears again...
Add following CSS to resolve the issue.


.div2:hover {
  display: flex;
}



